# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Tags: java, jnetpcap

I am trying to convert  .pcap files into .xml  files using this repo https://github.com/ISCX/ISCXFlowMeter for my deep learning project. I am new to java so I can't understand how to resolve this issue. I am using 32 bit jdk on 64 bit ubuntu. Seems like there is an issue with jnetpcap. Please someone help me as my deadline is very near. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it I would say you are missing an external library, like a Shared Object (.so) in Linux or a Dynamic Link Library (.dll) in Windows. If you shared the entire exception we could find out exactly where the exception is thrown and try to see if the code tells us where the library is expected to be found. Otherwise, I'd look at your classpath and make sure it contains the relevant dynamic libraries jnetpcap needs (reading the doc, jnetpcap is just a Java wrapper over existing non-Java utilities so that makes complete sense that there are non-Java dependencies to provide).

I tracked down the code in your stacktrace on Github and found that the exception was thrown [here](https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/com/slytechs/library/NativeLibrary.java#L119) while loading the libraries in [this annotation](https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/org/jnetpcap/Pcap.java#L239). Therefore, my guess is that you're missing one of the following libraries in your classpath: `wpcap`, `pcap`, `jnetpcap-pcap100`, `jnetpcap`. Two of them can be found [here](https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/tree/master/jnetpcap/native/linux/amd64), for Linux (Windows available in the same repo).

Comment: I have attached the picture.Check this out please.

Comment: The error is thrown here: https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/org/jnetpcap/Pcap.java#L500. I'll continue going down the code but in the meantime please print your classpath.

Comment: How can I print classpath? I mean for which class you want me to print classpath?

Comment: I also followed the last 2 answers but it didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048964/jnetpcap-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-com-slytechs-library-nativelibrary-dl

Comment: The classpath is something you set before starting the JVM (although it is possible to dynamically alter it, it's rarer). How do you launch your application? There are probably ways to print your classpath from Java, look it up on the internet.

Comment: Your exception is thrown either there (https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/com/slytechs/library/JNILibrary.java#L289) or line 299, can't tell from your stacktrace. The function was called using these parameters: https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/org/jnetpcap/Pcap.java#L239

Comment: Are you able to run the code through the debugger and put breakpoints in the locations I've shown you?

Comment: Check
/home/osama/New/ISCXFlowMeter/src/main/java/
/home/osama/New/jnetpcap.jar
/home/osama/New/commons-math3-3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
/home/osama/New/log4j-api-2.12.0.jar
/home/osama/New/log4j-core-2.12.0.jar

Comment: I am not using any IDE, I have to run this code on google colab for my project. so I will just use terminal for any operation.

Comment: Can you check please stackoverflow's link? Seems like there was a similar issue.

Comment: I tracked down the exception until the end: https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/blob/master/jnetpcap/jnetpcap-src-1.4.r1425-1/src/java1.5/com/slytechs/library/NativeLibrary.java#L119. You have to know what was the name of the library it tried to load though, which you could do using a debugger.

Comment: @a2nineu I don't think we need StackOverflow for this. We have all the code available on Github, we know exactly what is being executed.

Comment: I think library is libjnetpcap.so or libjnetpcap-pcap100.so.

Comment: Make sure the following binaries are available in the classpath: `wpcap`, `pcap`, `jnetpcap-pcap100`, `jnetpcap`. For Linux, you can find two of these binaries here: https://github.com/ruedigergad/clj-net-pcap/tree/master/jnetpcap/native/linux/amd64

Comment: You mean like this: CLASSPATH=/path/to/.sofiles

Comment: Depends how you launch the application. I'd same something like that if you do it on the CLI: `java -cp "path/to/jars:path/to/so/files" your/main/class`

Comment: class paths : /home/osama/New/ISCXFlowMeter/src/main/java/
/home/osama/New/jnetpcap.jar
/home/osama/New/commons-math3-3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
/home/osama/New/log4j-api-2.12.0.jar
/home/osama/New/log4j-core-2.12.0.jar
/home/osama/libjnetpcap.so
/home/osama/libjnetpcap-pcap100.so

Comment: This is not a valid classpath, paths must be separated with `:`. Can you use a debugger to figure out which library fails to load?

Comment: I used : in bashrc, this is the output of java program. Can you tell me please how can I use debugger? Thank you

Comment: An IDE would give you that out of the box, that's a very useful tool for some investigations.